# Can I make a Storage Space Pool from partitions rather than whole physical drives?

Tags: windows-10, storage-spaces

I want to use just 2 SSDs for the boot / system partitions AND a 2-way Storage Space Mirrored Pool.  So the boot / system partitions are going to have to reside on some portion of one SSD, then the remaining portion that SSD will join the second SSD in a mirrored storage space pool.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can not include mere partitions in storage spaces pools, but you are NOT forced to dedicate full disks either. You can create VHD/VHDX, these are virtual drives (Virtual Hard Disks) or simulated disks that you can mount, format etc from your drives.
Jose Barreto wrote a very good article (works on Windows 10 and server) : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/josebda/step-by-step-for-storage-spaces-tiering-in-windows-server-2012-r2

However, I wouldn't do this for critical data.

Answer (score 0):

**Not according to the documentation**

According to the [Storage Spaces in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12438/windows-10-storage-spaces) documentation you need at least 2 extra **drives** in addition to the one Windows is installed on.

> **What do I need to create a storage space?**
>
> You need at least two extra drives (in addition to the drive where Windows is installed). These drives can be internal or external hard drives, or solid state drives. You can use a variety of types of drives with Storage Spaces, including USB, SATA, and SAS drives

The corresponding [New-StoragePool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/new-storagepool?view=win10-ps) PowerShell command indicates physical disks rather than partitions must be used.

> -PhysicalDisks
>
> Accepts one or more PhysicalDisk objects as input. The Physical Disk CIM objects represent the physical disks to be added to the storage pool.

Comment: thiis is not correct. while the partitions need to come from multiple physical disks, it's possible to use partitions rather than entire disks.

Comment: @user1282931 - I've updated answer to indicate it isn't possible *according to the documentation* rather than categorically not.  If it is possible please post an alternative answer.

Comment: @matthias_buehlmann Ok, so how to do it? I have not found any example on how to add partitions instead of whole disks to Storage Spaces.