# Windows Storage Space, can it be created using partitions rather than physical disks?

Tags: partitioning, gpt, storage-spaces

Basically the same as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1447653/can-i-make-a-storage-space-pool-from-partitions-rather-than-whole-physical-drive) question which never got an answer..

With Windows Storage Spaces, I can by default create the following:

```
Physical Disk 1:
[//////////////////////////////////////////////////]
Physical Disk 2:
[//////////////////////////////////////////////////]

Virtual Disk (using both Disk 1 and Disk 2):
[GPT|///Partition 1///|///Partition 2/// etc ......................]
```

Instead of using the entire physical disks for the virtual disk, can I use only one partition on each disk for the virtual volume? Something like this:

```
Physical Disk 1:
[GPT|//Part1//|////////////////////////Part2////////////////////////]
Physical Disk 2:
[GPT|//Part1//|////////////////////////Part2////////////////////////]

Virtual Disk (USING ONLY Partition 2 OF EACH DISK):
[GPT | ///Partition 1/// | ///Partition 2/// etc ...............................]
```

Comment: No - see answer on linked question https://superuser.com/a/1505555/269373

Comment: This info seems to be incorrect as I was just able to do this